# hibernate annotation exception : Unable to create unique key constraint on table

Tags: hibernate, annotations, spring-data-jpa

My hibernate configuration as follows :

```
@Bean
            public JpaDialect hibernateJpaDialect() {
                HibernateJpaDialect hibernateJpaDialect = new HibernateJpaDialect();
                hibernateJpaDialect.setPrepareConnection(true);
                return hibernateJpaDialect;
            }

            @Bean
            public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {


                LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
                entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
                entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{BaseEntity.class.getPackage().getName()});
                entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter(dataSourceConfiguration));
                entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties(dataSourceConfiguration));
                entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaDialect(hibernateJpaDialect());
                return entityManagerFactoryBean;

            }
        @Bean
            public DataSource dataSource() {
                return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig(dataSourceConfiguration));

            }

            @Bean
            public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter(DataSourceConfiguration dataSourceConfiguration) {
                HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
                hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
                hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.valueOf(dataSourceConfiguration.getShowsql()));
                hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.valueOf(dataSourceConfiguration.getDdlGeneration()));
                return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
            }
    @Bean
        public EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter eclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter(DataSourceConfiguration dataSourceConfiguration) {
            EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter eclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
            eclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
            eclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.valueOf(dataSourceConfiguration.getShowsql()));
            eclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.valueOf(dataSourceConfiguration.getDdlGeneration()));
            return eclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter;
        }

        private HikariConfig hikariConfig(DataSourceConfiguration dataSourceConfiguration) {
            HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
            hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(dataSourceConfiguration.getDriver());
            hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(dataSourceConfiguration.getUrl());
            hikariConfig.setUsername(dataSourceConfiguration.getUser());
            hikariConfig.setPassword(dataSourceConfiguration.getPassword());
            return hikariConfig;
        }
     private Properties hibernateProperties(DataSourceConfiguration dataSourceConfiguration) {

            Properties properties = new Properties();

            properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", dataSourceConfiguration.getDdlGeneration());
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", dataSourceConfiguration.getDialect());
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", dataSourceConfiguration.getCurrentSession());
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", dataSourceConfiguration.getShowsql());
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", dataSourceConfiguration.getFormatsql());
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined", "true");


            return properties;
        }
```

Entity :

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
//@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "person_type")
@Table(name = "persons",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"number, person_type ,company_id"})
        },

        indexes = {
                @Index(name = "person_firstname_index", columnList = "firstname"),
                @Index(name = "person_lastname_index", columnList = "lastname"),
                @Index(name = "person_first_lastname_index", columnList = "firstname,lastname"),
                @Index(name = "person_email_index", columnList = "email"),
                @Index(name = "person_number_index", columnList = "number, company_id"),
                @Index(name = "person_mobile_index", columnList = "mobile"),
                @Index(name = "person_email_mobile_number_index", columnList = "number,email,mobile"),
        })
public abstract class Person extends BaseEntity implements ActorProfile {}
```

Exception : Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.orsbv.hcs.config.HCSRepositoryContext: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create unique key constraint (number, person_type ,company_id) on table persons: database column 'number, person_type ,company_id' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
 @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"number, person_type ,company_id"})
```

use

```
 @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"number", "person_type" , "company_id" })
```

String[] to provide the column names

Comment: thanks Dirk Deyne. as per hibernate documentation  " Be sure to use the database-level column names for the columnNames property of a @UniqueConstraint. For example, whilst for simple types the database-level column name may be the same as the entity-level property name, this is often not the case for relational properties."